# How to perform a function when element is tag x

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm looking to test what kind of tag something is, be it "IMG", "H1", etc..
I can't seem to get this code to work for me, not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
    String.prototype.addFormElement = function(){


    if(self == "P"){
        console.log("I'm a paragraph");
    }
    else if(self == "IMG"){
        console.log("I'm a iamge");
    }
    else if(self == "A"){
        console.log("I'm a link");
    }
    else if(self == "H1" || 
                    self == "H2" || 
                    self == "H3" || 
                    self == "H4" || 
                    self == "H5" || 
                    self == "H6"){
        console.log("I'm a header");
    }
    else if(self == "TABLE"){
        console.log("I'm a table");
    }
    else if(self == "UL" || 
            self == "OL" || 
            self == "LI"){
        console.log("I'm a list");
    }
    else if(self == '#text'){
        console.log("shoot me");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Not recognize");
    }

    return 0;

}

//==============================================================================

//=============================================================================

    var ezgrp = document.getElementsByClassName("ez-group");


    for(var i = 0;i<ezgrp.length;i++){

        let ezchild = ezgrp[i].childNodes;


        for(var j = 0;j<ezchild.length;j++){

            var plz = "" + ezchild[j].nodeName.toString();
            plz.addFormElement();

        }
    }
```

This is the JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/xg342n6w/13/

No matter what it returns "Not recognized"

I convert it to string, the function is a prototype of String, but it never recognizes it.

Comment: `element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'p'`, there's no need for a big prototyped method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` is the `window` object. Your string object is `this`. To get the value of that string object you have to use `valueOf` or `toString` methods:

```
String.prototype.addFormElement = function() {

    var v = this.valueOf(); // get the value of this string

    if(v === "P"){
        console.log("I'm a paragraph");
    }
    else if(v === "IMG"){
        console.log("I'm a iamge");
    }
    // ...
}
```

**Note:** Perhaps you want to use `.toUpperCase` on `v` before comparing it to those upercased tag names strings in case they're lowercased.

Comment: Thank you, my mistake. It's working perfectly now :) it comes uppercase so no need to change it

Answer (score 0):

`self` is the not carrying the reference of your tags, you should have used `this` instead and get `toString` result

```
if(this.toString() === "P"){
    console.log("Output: I'm a paragraph");
}
```

I have updated the js fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/xg342n6w/15/.